# Swapping numbers in place

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, thus the question.
I'm trying to swap two numbers without using a third temporary variable. The code is fairly simple.

```
public static void swapInPlace(int a, int b){
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int a = 12;
        int b = 7;
        swapInPlace(a, b);
        System.out.println("a: " + a + " b: " + b);

    }
```

The logic runs fine in the debugger, but outputs the same values for a and b. I understand the same is happening because the copied values were used by the swapInPlace function.

Now if I have to make this function work in C++, I would just change my method signature as

```
public static void swapInPlace(int& a, int& b)
```

But since that can't be done in java, my question is how can I make this thing work in java.

Comment: The plain answer is either you can´t or you have to use a wrapper class for the `int` in order to be able to use the reference to the object.

Comment: @KevinEsche I never thought about this, but would using `Integer` work?

Comment: @MrHug no it´s not. It´s the same as you would like to use a swap function for a `String`.

Comment: Using `Integer` doesn't work either.

Comment: @KevinEsche Ok thanks, just wasn't sure and wanted to check :)

Comment: @MrHug Integer is **immutable**, so it won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have said, you need to use a wrapper. This is a short example on how to do it.

```
private class IntWrap{
    int value;

    public IntWrap(int v){ this.value=v; }
}

public static void swapInPlace(IntWrap a, IntWrap b){
    a.value = a.value + b.value;
    b.value = a.value - b.value;
    a.value = a.value - b.value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntWrap a = new IntWrap(12);
    IntWrap b = new IntWrap(7);
    swapInPlace(a, b);
    System.out.println("a: " + a.value + " b: " + b.value);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java is **always pass by value**. In some cases, though, you are passing a reference and thus is able to change contents of an object.

You can use *AtomicInteger* as a mutable wrapper of *int* for example purpose.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SwapInPlaceMain {
    public static void swapInPlace(AtomicInteger a, AtomicInteger b) {
        a.set(a.get() + b.get());
        b.set(a.get() - b.get());
        a.set(a.get() - b.get());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(12);
        AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(7);
        swapInPlace(a, b);
        System.out.println("a: " + a + " b: " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there not overhead problems with using AtomicIntegers (due to concurrency features)? Why not create an inner class as a wrapper? Performance-wise, there should be better results, no?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Sure. I mean it solely **for example purpose**.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 TS code is obviously experiencing overflow problems, so no need for further optimizations.

Comment: TS stands for *Topic Starter*. Not sure if it is common abbreviation at SO.

Comment: Ah! I believe OP (original poster) is more common here, but thanks anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, create an inner class and create an object of it, this class could have both variables and return the object in your `swapInPlace()` method.

Another one could be to pass an array, for example:

```
class Swap {
    public static void swapInPlace(int array[]){
        array[0] = array[0] + array[1];
        array[1] = array[0] - array[1];
        array[0] = array[0] - array[1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int array[] = new int []{12, 7};
        swapInPlace(array);
        System.out.println("a: " + array[0] + " b: " + array[1]);

    }
}
```

And the output of the above program is:

```
a: 7 b: 12
```

Answer (score 1):

A ( probably controversial ) way to achieve this is simply to use a macro pre-processor.

Java may not by default include support for macros, but there is nothing preventing you using a preprocessor.  I do use the C preprocessor myself with Java from time to time.

It's worth noting that Java people tend to foam at the mouth when anyone suggests this.  There's no rational reason for this but chronic fear, IMO, as preprocessors are perfectly legitimate programming tools.  The Java compiler is not friendly to preprocessors, but there are ways around this ( I wrote a compiler modification for this purpose but it's not required to use a preprocessor, it's just convenient for me ).

There are many preprocessors out there.  Notable choices are the C preprocessor and the [generic preprocessor ( GPP )](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP).  The venerable M4 system also leaps to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to send the values to the function by "reference". You are passing values rather than their reference address hence values don't change even after the function is called.

This code will sort your issue

```
public static void swapInPlace(int &a, int &b){
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int a = 12;
        int b = 7;
        swapInPlace(a, b);
        System.out.println("a: " + a + " b: " + b);

    }
```